# sailsjs generate model attributes

Tags: model, attributes, sails.js, bootstrapping

I try to set the model attributes in the bootstrap function, because I try to generate the attributes (instead of setting they by hand).

I've tried this for the product model:

```
 
  module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
      ...
      generate(function(attributes){
          sails.models.product.attributes = attributes;
      });
  ...
  };
```

but it does not seem to work.
What am I doing wrong?
Or is there other options to resolve my issue?

Note: I have asked the question on [github page Issue #1107](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1107), too.